# Is there a way to provide a mock for entryComponents in an Angular test?

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular-material, testbed

I want to test an Angular component (`MyTableComponent`) which uses MatDialog to display another component (`DefaultDialogComponent`)

**my-table.component.ts**

```js
import { MatDialog } from "@angular/material/dialog";
export class MyTableComponent {
  constructor(private _dialog: MatDialog) {}

  openDefaultDialog(data): void {
    this._dialog.open(DefaultDialogComponent, {
      restoreFocus: false,
      autoFocus: false,
      data: data,
      width: "600px",
    });
  }
}
```

To test this I override `BrowserAnimationsModule` to inject the dialog component in entryComponents

**my-table.component.spec.ts**

```js
...
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
        MyTableComponent,
        DefaultDialogComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule
        // Material
        MatTableModule,
        MatDialogModule
    ],
})
    .overrideModule(BrowserAnimationsModule, {
        set: {
            entryComponents: [DefaultDialogComponent],
        },
    })
    .compileComponents();
...
```

The problem with this test implementation is that I have to include in `MyTableComponent` every dependency from `DefaultDialogComponent` in order for the test to compile.

What I want is to be able to inject a Mock component instead of `DefaultDialogComponent`, but when I do so the test does not compile:

> No component factory found for RegionDialogWithMapComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

This is the mock component of `DefaultDialogComponent` I am using:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'default-dialog', // same as original component
  template: '',
})
class RegionDialogWithMapComponentMock {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data) {}
}
```

Comment: How are you registering  the mock component?

Comment: @VimalPatel I declare it before the TestBed configuration and I use the mock instead  `DefaultDialogComponent`

Comment: Please share the code and also what error you are getting by doing that?